# Create setup.exe included database (sql) in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, installation, installshield, setup-project

I have created a program in C# which is connected with the database in SQL server as localhost. When I create setup file with instalShield, the program successfully installed, but it doesn't show the data from database and as such can not be used fully.
Can you help me what should I do to make a full setup.exe which can install everywhere including all files and database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use from setup factory soft ware . 
It's powerful for create  setup.
http://download.cnet.com/Setup-Factory/3000-2216_4-10002374.html